# Do any other Frost Giants have the power of illusion?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

For those who've not seen the recent Thor movie, and don't wish to be ***horribly*** spoiled, look away now. I'm about to reveal a real doozy.

Look away now!

> We know that Loki is a Frost Giant, and has powers of illusion, but do any other Frost Giants in Marvel canon have illusion-based powers?

It seems odd that he is the only one.

Comment: Any chance of a comment on the downvote?

Comment: Frost giants had the power of illusion even before they showed up in Marvel comics. One of the most enduring Norse myths had the giant king Utgard-Loki use illusions to trick Thor and Loki in a contest against the Frost Giants. The illusions were so incredible Thor and Loki had no chance of discerning they were being tricked. This story has existed for over a thousand years...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand it, Loki is and always has been educated purely as an Asgardian.

The techniques he's learned are Asgardian techniques, taught by Asgardian teachers (and possibly some from other realms, like the Dark Elf in the Thor animated movie).  He has a real affinity for the skills he's learned.

By and large, Frost Giant society does not encourage thought or magical skill - they tend to develop their natural affinities for ice magic, if that innate skill is potent, but otherwise they don't spend much time studying magic at all.

Loki is certainly evidence that

> Frost Giants CAN learn such magic

but that doesn't necessarily lead to the fact that there ARE Frost Giants who have.  As far as I know, there are no Frost Giants from their native society who are proficient in the arts of Illusion, as Loki is.

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes, in the canon Marvel Earth-616 continuity, other Frost Giants have the magical power of illusion, and indeed some of them are quite capable users of magic. The most well known representative is a character taken directly from myth named [Utgard-Loki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Utgard-Loki_(Earth-616)).

[image]

- A direct descendant of the first ice deity of the Asgardian realm, [Ymir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ymir_(Marvel_Comics)), Utgard Loki is a Frost Giant whose magical capacity is legendary even in Asgard. While Ymir's magical capacity is bound within his body, his descendants are all potentially capable of magic and some are as good or the equal of the [Aesir of Asgard](http://www.ravenkindred.com/RBGods.html). Utgard Loki made his first appearance in Thor #272 - The Day the Thunder Failed! released by Marvel on June 1, 1978.

> - At least some Frost Giants have the power to create magical illusions. Utgard-Loki is a master of the sorcery of the Frost Giants. His powers to create illusions are greater than those of other know Frost Giants. He is also capable of creating potions to enhance his magical abilities.
> - Utgard Loki can cause the weather of Jotunheim to grow even more frigid. He once transformed Karnilla the Norn Queen into a bird. Utgard-Loki first encountered the Asgardian gods Thor and Loki many centuries ago when the two gods came to his castle. Utgard-Loki demanded that they perform a series of what appeared to be simple feats, which in actuality proved immensely difficult. REF: **This is a classic story of Young Thor and Loki: [Thor's Visit to Jotenheim: The Giant's Country](http://www.mythome.org/bfcxxxix.html)**
> - Using his magical powers of illusion, Utgard-Loki had disguised the objects of the feats that he had Thor and Loki to perform. Hence, in lifting appeared to be a cat's paw, Thor actually was lifting the immense bulk of Jormungand, the Midgard Serpent. Thor and Loki fared impressively in coping with these challenges, despite Utgard-Loki's deceptions. **REF: Marvel Comics Wiki entry - [Giants of Jotenheim](http://marvel.com/universe/Giants_of_Jotunheim)**

- Utgard-Loki's magical illusions were so great, he was completely able to deceive all of Thor and Loki's senses. They were unaware of what was transcending during the challenges and were unable to make their way back to Jotenheim once they left. His feats in the Marvel Universe have been no less impressive despite his very limited number of appearances.